# How can I automatically get the public IP of a windows machine on startup and have it sent to me (through email for example)

Tags: windows

I know that on linux, but how can I do that on Windows?
I thought on putting the script in the startup folder, and have it execute a command to check the public IP (a nslookup with opendns for instance), and send it to another machine or email remotely, but I'm not familiarised with it.

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use certutil.exe and ipify.org

```
certutil.exe -URLcache -split -f "http://ipify.org" c:\ip.txt
```

After this it only depends how you want to send it. If it's email, you can run a powershell script to send send one. You can see such example script 
[here](https://www.howtogeek.com/120011/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-send-email-from-the-command-line-in-windows-without-extra-software/)

Comment: Thanks, though I'm having some trouble on using PowerShell to send the email.